# Set default value to null in Spring @Value on a java.util.Set variable

Tags: java, spring, spring-el

Having an interesting issue with the Spring @Value annotation using SpEL. Setting default value of null works for a String variable. However, for a Set variable it doesn't.

So, this works (varStr is null):

```
@Value("${var.string:#{NULL}}")
private String varStr;
```

while this doesn't (varSet now contains one element with "#{NULL}"):

```
@Value("#{'${var.set:#{NULL}}'.split(',')}")
private Set<String> varSet;
```

The question is how to make this work with a Set variable as well so it would be set to null by default.

Your help will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: It seems *very* strange to want to default an injected dependency like this to `null`.

Comment: While I agree that this is very strange desire, I wondering why did you put this expression into quotes, i.e. `'${var.set:#{NULL}}'` ?

Comment: Personally I never use Field injection, and always use Constructor injection. In this manner you have control over setting the field value to `null` in the constructor if you really need to.

Comment: The external var.set property is an optional property (it's not always set). So if it's not defined we need to default the varSet object to null. Just a business requirement.

Answer (score 5):

You could try injecting the `@Value` into an array instead of a Set.  Then in a `@PostConstruct` init block convert that into the desired Set instance.  Spring appears to be injecting an empty array (not null) when no such property exists (note the empty default value in the `@Value` string).  When it does exist it splits on comma by default.

Like this:

```
@Value("${some.prop:}")
private String[] propsArr;
private Set<String> props;

@PostConstruct
private void init() throws Exception {
    props = (propsArr.length == 0) ? null : Sets.newHashSet(propsArr);
}
```

I will just make one other suggestion.  I recommend that you don't use `null` at all, but rather an empty Set instead.  Null tends to be error-prone and typically doesn't convey any more info than an empty collection. Your case may well be different - this is just a general recommendation.

BTW - that `Sets.newHashSet(...)` call is from [Google's Guava library](https://github.com/google/guava/wiki).  Highly recommended.

Comment: Thank you Pedorro. Was trying do it all using SpEL and thus avoid @PostConstruct and extra coding. Still, went with you solution and it worked.

Answer (score 3):

You can create a PropertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer. This bean will intercept the property source values and allow you to configure them.

```
@Configuration
@ComponentScan
class ApplicationConfig {

@Bean
public static PropertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer placeholderConfigurer() {
  PropertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer c = new PropertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer();
  c.setNullValue("");
  return c;
}
```

Reference: http://blog.codeleak.pl/2015/09/placeholders-support-in-value.html

Which will default an empty string to null.

Comment: Sorry, doesn't seem to make a difference in my case.

Answer (score 1):

Unless you can find an elegant solution to get around this, you can inject the property into your contructor as a `String` and then `Split()` it yourself or default to `null`.

```
class Foo {

    private Set<String> varSet;

    public Foo(@Value("${var.string:#{NULL}}") String varString) {
        varSet = (varString == null) ? null : new HashSet<>(Arrays.asList(varString.split(",")));
    }
}
```

Comment: Yes, will probably have to resolve to getting a String and then applying split.